# Android EditText with chips

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-chips

I have an app where I have a list of objects in a fragment. Once I click on one of these objects a text will appear into an EditText but as a chip. This chip will have a delete 'x' only, no images.

It's not a autocompletetextview but an EditText with text inside chips.

I checked online and actually there are some libraries but too buggy and most of them use the Autocompletetextview.

I thought I would need to override some drawables method in the EditText but to be honest I'm not sure since I'm new in Android.

Screenshot taken from Pinterest app:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: I added a screenshot from Pinterest. The idea is the same basically. It's an EditText with chips (with the clear button only for each of them)